# jQuery: Using mouseover and mouseout in combination with toggleClass

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a small web application where I have some clickable areas and some non-clickable areas. While the user's mouse pointer is over a clickable area, the area gets highlighted and the pointer changes to a hand. I also have some areas which are initially non-clickable and then become clickable and vice-versa once a button is clicked. I'm using the `toggleClass` method on these areas. But I can't seem to use the `mouseover` and `mouseout` methods on these specific areas.

When I click on the button, I want to change the mouse pointer as well as the background color on hovering the pointer over the Show Answer and the Submit tabs and on clicking again, I want to revert them back to their default state.Right now, I can only change the pointer.

**HTML**

```
<div id="help" class="hover">Help</div>
<div id="switchplayer" class="hover">Switch to Two player</div>
<div id="showanswer">Show Answer</div>
<div id="submit">Submit</div>
<div id="start" class="hover">Start</div>

<button>Click me!</button>
```

**jQuery**
    $('button').click(function() {
    $('#showanswer,#submit').toggleClass('hover');
    });

```
$('.hover').mouseover(function() {
   $(this).css('background-color','red'); 
}).mouseout(function() {
       $(this).css('background-color',''); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
div {
border:1px solid black;
}

.hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    cursor:hand;
}
```

Comment: Explain your question, and post the code, *in your question*. JS Fiddle is a bonus, but the question should stand alone (though illustrative demonstrations/reproductions are extremely helpful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with this simple CSS:

```
.hover:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cT3M9/3/

Then it will work as expected.

If however you need javascript for this task you should use `on` to delegate events:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','red');
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '');
    }
}, '.hover');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cT3M9/6/

Comment: Yeah I needed the javascript solution. Thanks a lot mate! But could you explain why my code wasn't working?

Comment: Because event is not attached to rows without `hover` class. When you add it later you have to rebind events again or use delegation with `on`.

Comment: Thanks I got it! +1 for a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

As dfsq points out, the simplest way to do this is simply through CSS. However, the reason your code isn't working is that the `mouseover` and `mouseout` methods are only applied to elements that have the `hover` class *when those methods are executed*. The event handers are *not* attached retroactively to new elements that meet the original selection criteria. To apply your event handler code to elements that acquire that class later, use the variation of the [.on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like so:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.hover', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','red'); 
}).on('mouseout', '.hover', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color',''); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks!But I had to select dfsq's answer because he was the first one to answer.You get a +1 though :)